# What PDO driver to use with mariadb?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mariadb

After replacing mysql with mariadb, I encountered the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'could not find driver' in /var/www/inlcude/config.php:5\nStack
>   trace:\n#0 /var/www/inlcude/config.php(5):
>   PDO->__construct('mysql:dbname=my...', 'apache', 'ABCDE...')\n#1
>   /var/www/html/index(21): require('/var/www/inlcude/con...')\n#2
>   {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/inlcude/config.php on line 5

I have read through the following two related questions, but can't find the answer there:
[PDO and MariaDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195013/pdo-and-mariadb)
[PDOException “could not find driver”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

`yum list pdo_mysql`, `yum list php5-mysql`, `yum list php5-mariadb` all returns no matching package. What is the name of the PDO driver for mariadb to be used on Fedora 20 (red hat)?

Just to add, `php-pdo` is already installed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By trial and error, it turns out that I need to install [mysqlnd](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/php-mysqlnd/) to get the PDO driver.

```
yum install php-mysqlnd
```

Don't ask me why or how it works because I have absolutely no idea.

Comment: MariaDB is supposed to be a binary compatible fork of MySQL. You won't find a specific driver for it, but the MySQL one should work.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for which PDO driver I needed for MySQL using an updated PHP package, php56u-mysqlnd was what I needed

Answer (score 2):

MarriaDB is branch of mysql. For installation PDO driver for it, install php-pdo and php-mysql packages

```
wget http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-3.noarch.rpm
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-5.rpm
rpm -Uvh remi-release-5*.rpm epel-release-5*.rpm
```

And after this you can install pdo and mysql from remi repositories

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install php-pdo
yum --enablerepo=remi install php-mysql
```