# Can I use the same PDO dsn for connecting to mariadb?

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I am looking to use mariadb and wanted to know if I can using the same was DSN I was using for mysql:

```
mysql:host=localhost;dbname=wp;port=8889
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO and MariaDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195013/pdo-and-mariadb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, as MariaDB is essentially a [drop in replacement](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/the-mariadb-library/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/) for MySQL. So anything that works with MySQL, including the DSN should work in MariaDB too.

Comment: There's some exceptions, MariaDB can take a while to merge newer features from MySQL, but for 99% of it there's no difference.