# PHP SEARCH SQL - Website

Tags: php, mariadb

I've this coding that works fine on localhost. But in my website it doesnt, and I guess its due do MARIADB version 10.1.24

Here's the code:

```
$search1 = @$_GET['valuelo'];
$search2 = @$_GET['valuear'];
$search3 = @$_GET['valueco'];
$search4 = @$_GET['valuero'];
$search5 = @$_GET['valuefl'];
$search6 = @$_GET['valuelu'];
$search7 = @$_GET['valuetr'];
$search8 = @$_GET['valuepo'];



   $sql = "SELECT * FROM location, area, condition, rooms, floor, luxury, trendy, pool
     WHERE 'location' LIKE '%$search1%'
     AND 'area' LIKE '%$search2%'
     AND 'condition' LIKE '%$search3%'
     AND 'rooms' LIKE '%$search4%'
     AND 'floor' LIKE '%$search5%'
     AND 'luxury' LIKE '%$search6%'
     AND 'trendy' LIKE '%$search7%'
     AND 'pool' LIKE '%$search8%'";
```

Here's the error:

ERROR: Could not able to execute

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  location, area, condition, rooms, floor, luxury, trendy,
        pool
    WHERE  locationbw LIKE '%%'
      AND  area LIKE '%%'
      AND  condition LIKE '%%'
      AND  rooms LIKE '%%'
      AND  floor LIKE '%%'
      AND  luxury LIKE '%%'
      AND  trendy LIKE '%%'
      AND  pool LIKE '%%'
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition, rooms, floor, luxury, trendy, pool WHERE locationbw LIKE '%%' ' at line 1

Please help me! I see everything right

Comment: First, you have `locationbw` in the error but not in the string. Why is that? Second, you are not concatenating this. Why is that? Your `$sql` value, as shown here, shouldn't work, so I assume this isn't the actual code. It also appears you have an extra ` in there somewhere, based on the error. I would also suggest using pdo so you can used prepared statements for some added security. And, why do you have the @ symbol before your get? You should be checking the existence those variables as well, and sanitizing them accordingly as well

Comment: PDO - http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Comment: Please tell me you haven't got this running on a live web server ... anywhere.

Comment: Your query is a 12 year old script kiddie's wet dream. Please start using [PDO Prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Might as go back to PHP 4 and make sure register globals are on as well.

Comment: Also: [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and back ticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql)

Comment: @adpro I changed to locationbw to see the result, but it gave me the same error.  It works on Xampp without ' ' on location, area, rooms, floor, luxury etc. I only get this error online. What do I need to change?

Comment: Are `location, area, condition, rooms, floor, luxury, trendy, pool` tables or columns? It's breaking right there.

Comment: @CD001 nice participation. Give me your instagram

Comment: @aynber tables and collumns name. I thought the same, thats why I changed a collumn to locationbw to doesnt match the tablename. But the error started the same way

Comment: I'd really suggest rethinking your query, so it makes more sense. Right now, it's a mess.

Comment: You still have a bunch of issues. You're using `@$_GET`. That's just suppressing errors for that statement, right? Check to see something exists in that variable rather than just suppressing errors. Also, if you're going to do a straight query like this, you have to sanitize that input. Again, PDO is your friend. It helps you be more secure. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195013/pdo-and-mariadb

Comment: The reason you want to sanitize your input is because someone could easily exploit stuff, throw in come SQL code that does strange things, and compromises all of your data. Popular software has been subject to SQL Injection, including PHPBB years ago. I was able to log into many administrator account by manipulating the username to ignore checking the password. You will certainly make the same mistakes, so using PDO will help you stay more secure. Please consider it, and do not put this SQL in production anywhere.

Comment: @adpro thank you so much for your advice. I'll look into it!  The website is blocked btw...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose the table-name and column-name into backquote (`) else query will break at the point where you use the MariaDB keyword. In your query **"condition"** is MariaDB keyword

> "SELECT * FROM `location`, `area`, `condition`, `rooms`, `floor`, `luxury`, `trendy`, `pool` WHERE `location` LIKE '%$search1%'
>        AND `area` LIKE '%$search2%'
>        AND `condition` LIKE '%$search3%'
>        AND `rooms` LIKE '%$search4%'
>        AND `floor` LIKE '%$search5%'
>        AND `luxury` LIKE '%$search6%'
>        AND `trendy` LIKE '%$search7%'
>        AND `pool` LIKE '%$search8%'";

Comment: So I should change condition to another name right?

Comment: Yes, You can. But always try to keep the table and column name in backquote (`) .

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL statement is not correct in so many ways that it surprises me it's producing anything good in your development environment.

A good way to proceed in these situations is to concatenate the results of every single table search into a single output, using `UNION` statements. Provided the tables share a minimum number of identically named and typed fields (signally, `Id` and `Name`):

```
SELECT 'Location' AS Type, Id AS ID, Name AS Ref
FROM location
WHERE location_field LIKE '%$search1%'
  UNION
SELECT 'Area' AS Type, Id AS ID, Name AS Ref
FROM area
WHERE area_field LIKE '%$search2%'
  UNION
SELECT 'Room' AS Type, Id AS ID, Name AS Ref
FROM rooms
WHERE rooms_field LIKE '%$search3%'
  UNION
...
```

On the top of that, additional checks on the value of the search fields would help building (or skipping) `WHERE` clauses. Last but not least, use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of building your query strings manually.

Comment: Thank you! This is not my area, but Im trying! It looks better!